# Bound on norm of the curvature from Chern class

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, chern-classes

Let $M$ be an oriented closed $6$-manifold. $V$ be an hermitian complex vector bundle of dimension $4$ on $M.$ Hence $c^3(V)\in H^6(M,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ can be thought of as an integer and only depends on the topology of $V$. Given a unitary connection $A$ on $V$, $c^3(V)$ can be obtained from the curvature $2$-form $F_A$. Is there a way to relate this to the $L^3$ norm-square of $F_A:\int_M|F_A|^3?$

Comment: You are looking for a bound of the form $\int_m |F_A|^3 \geq  C c^3(V)$, right? A bound the other way seems unlikely as we could intentionally choose a very non-flat connection.

Comment: @WillSawin Indeed I realized that. But even some sort of equality with some extra terms would be potentially interesting to me (if it exists).